# _com_error, comdef.h -Catching exceptions in D3D12

Tags: windows, exception, winapi, com

I'm experiencing a strange `_com_error` exception during graphics rendering after attempting to read data from an upload heap in the shader.

After looking up `_com_error`, it appears one needs to catch it like an exception:

```
try
{
    // attempt to present the scene
    System.SwapChain->Present( App.Video.Option.Set(videoSet::VERTICAL_SYNC) ? 1 : 0 );
}
catch(_com_error &x)
{
    app_error( x.ErrorMessage() );
}
```

However, to use `_com_error`, I apparently need to include **comdef.h**, and when I include **comdef.h**, I get a lot of warnings and errors. The first set of the warnings/errors seem to be coming from a secondary include that is apparently included in comdef.h, `C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\ole2.h`. The first thing I tried was to wrap my include (I'm using Visual Studio 2022):

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <comdef.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work at all, even though it does with every other file I've ever tried to include in my project. Even with this, I still get warnings, which are treated as errors. Here are a few of them:

```
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(92,41): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(92,41): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(92,41): error C2491: 'OleBuildVersion': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(92,36): error C2065: 'VOID': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(94,50): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(94,50): error C2491: 'WriteFmtUserTypeStg': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(94,47): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(94,50): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'LPSTORAGE'
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(95,34): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(95,34): error C2491: 'ReadFmtUserTypeStg': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(95,31): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(95,34): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'LPSTORAGE'
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(100,43): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(100,43): error C2491: 'OleInitialize': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(100,40): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(100,43): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'LPVOID'
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(107,36): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(107,36): error C2491: 'OleQueryLinkFromData': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(107,33): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(107,36): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'LPDATAOBJECT'
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(108,38): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(108,38): error C2491: 'OleQueryCreateFromData': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(108,35): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(108,38): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'LPDATAOBJECT'
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(113,25): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(113,25): error C2491: 'OleCreate': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(113,22): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(113,25): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(118,27): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(118,27): error C2491: 'OleCreateEx': definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(118,24): error C2065: 'IN': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Ole2.h(118,27): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
```

Does this have something to do with the Windows Kit I'm using? I remember trying to do this in the past, several years ago, and ran into the same exact issue, and ended up giving up trying to catch the exception.

Can anyone point out my ignorance in this situation? Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the problem with [these samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/search?q=IDXGISwapChain)? Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: I did figure out how to suppress the warnings. It is done through project > c++ > External Includes > External Header Warning Level. So now I only need to deal with real errors, but there are still quite a few of them. @YangXiaoPo-MSFT: I will see if I can test those. If not, I will try to build a minimal example. Sorry, wait, by problem, did you mean with the exception or with `_com_error`? Unfortunately, I am using Diligent Engine as part of my graphics engine, and the problem only occurs when I use dynamic buffers and then try to access the buffer in a shader, so its likely very specific.

Comment: You did give me the obvious idea of creating a new project and trying to use _com_error in that (which I didn't consider), and that works. So its clearly some project setting or some other include that is causing the errors. Time to try to narrow it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by another header include using `#undef VOID`, along with removing several other defines that Windows uses.

I am being forced to include `comdef.h` above that include to make it work, but doing that solved my problem. If anyone else runs into similar errors, make sure you include `comdef.h` along with other windows headers, in case some header decides to bomb the Microsoft #define 'namespace'.